# Rails 3 Form: Random Parameter not being updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form; everything works well -- except one parameter is, somehow, not being updated. Everything else is accepted and populated, except this one parameter, which always seems to be blank no matter what I do. The parameter is "file_name".

This is my form:

```
<h2 align="center"> User </h2>
<div id="left_half">
  <div class="ibox">
    <h3 align="center"> User Profile</h3>

    <div class="left">
      <%= f.label :file_name, 'File name', class: 'field_label' %>
    </div>
    <div class ="right">
      <%= f.text_field :file_name, class: 'small-text-area' %>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
      <%= f.label :email, 'Email', class: 'field_label' %>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'small-text-area' %>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
```

This is my controller create action:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])#user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'Entry was successfully added to database'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable

  validates :file_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 30}
  validates :email, length: {maximum: 45, minimum: 10}
  ...
  ...
```

Also, here's a console session:

```
User.create(:file_name => "John", :email => "Ssdafsafasfafomething")
```

Which successfully creates and saves the new user. Also, on the webapp, it displays correctly -- with the filename shown. So mass assignment seems to work for filename...? But then, when I enter data into the form on the webapp, the entry fails, claiming that the file_name can't be blank -- even though I just typed stuff into it!

Comment: Can you see all the params when you look at the Rails Server log/output?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhhh....I got it

A while back, I tried adding extra functionality to my form. I had not yet updated my model so, in favor of expedience, I simply set the form's new text fields to update some arbitrary parameter in my class. This arbitrary parameter was...file_name.

Lesson learned: in your forms, have your parameters only get updated by ONE text_field. It seems obvious now, but I spent HOURS down the rabbit hole on this -- beware!